# Android app crashed if the main activity isn't MainActivity

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to start with the Loading view but always crashed when I open it if the main activity in AndroidManifiest.xml isn't MainActivity. On the emulator is fine but the problem only is when install the apk in a phone. Any help?

AndroidManifiest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.daniel.jaentodayapp">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label=""
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoadingScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

LoadingScreen

```
public class LoadingScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading_screen);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoadingScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}}
```

Layout Loading Screen

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_loading_screen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.daniel.jaentodayapp.LoadingScreen">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/pcarga"></LinearLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

This is the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.daniel.jaentodayapp, PID: 18967
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.daniel.jaentodayapp/com.example.daniel.jaentodayapp.LoadingScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                  at com.example.daniel.jaentodayapp.LoadingScreen.onCreate(LoadingScreen.java:13)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                  at com.example.daniel.jaentodayapp.LoadingScreen.onCreate(LoadingScreen.java:13) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                  at com.example.daniel.jaentodayapp.LoadingScreen.onCreate(LoadingScreen.java:13) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
               Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 255322380 byte allocation with 12571568 free bytes and 126MB until OOM
                  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
                  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3955)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:574)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:203)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:199)
                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:195)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                  at com.example.daniel.jaentodayapp.LoadingScreen.onCreate(LoadingScreen.java:13) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `startActivity()` only from the main thread. If you want to make the call from a `Runnable` use a `Handler` If you call `.run()` instead of `.start()` the runnable would be executed on the calling thread

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading_screen);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoadingScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

> Never put wait timer in loading screen unless necessary, call the MainActvity in onResume as by the time onResume is called, Sytem finishes the operations to load the App.

There are many examples on Stack overflow on how to implement Splash Screen (Loading Screen) in good way. meanwhile you can use this solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading_screen);

    mHandler.postDelayed(moveToMain, 3000);
}

private final Runnable moveToMain = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoadingScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
       Intent intent = new Intent(LoadingScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       finish();
     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
        }, 3000);
```

please finish your activity while you start your new activity .
instead of finishing onpause()
This is an issue of running a UIThread on main thread .
hope that answer the question .
if you paste or show your stacktrace or error log it would make more easy to find a solution for this.

Thanks